# Constraints Solver Library C++

Tags: library, c++, cad

I am writing a basic CAD application where a user can create 2D constraints between points.

There will be a number of different constraint types and so I am looking for a free general constraints solver library which can handle a few (~20) simple non-linear constraints.

My initial searches came across the [Cassowary Algorithm](https://github.com/starwing/amoeba) which works great for linear constraints (i.e. x<sub>2</sub> = x<sub>1</sub> + distance) but fails to handle non-linear ones (x<sup>2</sup> + y<sup>2</sup> = distance).

Ideally I would like the library to be as lightweight as possible (header only would be even better), fast (as I would like to update the point's positions as the user moves a point around) and in either C or C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google OR-Tools is a software suite for optimization, containing many different solvers.

The [CP-SAT Solver](https://developers.google.com/optimization/cp/cp_solver) is a non-linear solver, ideal for my use.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! While it obviously must match your requirements as you self-answer, you didn't even include where to find it. Could you please **[edit]** your answer and add a few details? For a guide, see e.g. [our discussion on what makes an answer high quality](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/356/185). Thanks!